# Converting NSString number to float

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am having difficulties converting `NSString`'s that have numbers into `floats` or something more useful.

I have tried the following code:

```
NSString *mystring = @"123"
    int currentBidAmount = [myString integerValue];
```

No problem there.

Then `float`

```
NSString *mystring = @"123.95"
        float currentBidAmount = [myString floatValue];
```

Again, no problem

However when `myString` has three decimals - I get an inaccurate number. For Example:

```
NSString *mystring = @"1.123.95"
            float currentBidAmount = [myString floatValue];
```

It prints out: `1`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

The goal is to have two `NSString`s - get their values and add them up for a total amount. So I need more accuracy than just I am getting now.

Comment: So what was your expected result in this situation ?

Comment: For the last string in my example I wanted a float value: 1.123.95

Comment: Is this float value `1.123.95`?

Comment: can u say it is the float value 1.123.95 or double

Comment: A float value can only store a single decimal separator. Is 1123.95 the desired float?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes that result would be acceptable 1123.95

Comment: @Tander Since the group separator is the same as the decimal separator, how would you know if the value '1.234.567' is '1234.567' or '1234567.00'?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The NSString will always represent the correct value with the correct group separators. I format the number before I arrive at this point in my project. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The decimal separator and group separators must be different.  This is true in common usage and in any practical data processing scenario.  And the NSString XXXXValue functions are not designed to handle non-standard separators -- for that you need NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

While you can get an `NSString` integer or floatValue you should use `NSNumberFormatter`for that. Why? The decimal and grouping separator varies between countries and the floatValue code does only account for . as decimal separator. So users with a locale using a , are doomed.

How to:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
float myFloat = [numberFormatter numberFromString:myString].floatValue;
```

Read up on various settings here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Was going to write the same thing. Also continuing with the use of `NSDecimalNumber` for example is much more precise and safe than directly converting to float.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put two commas for a float value

this code works fins:

```
       NSString *example = @"13124.4153";
       float floatValue = [example floatValue];
       NSLog(@"value = %f", floatValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I managed to solve the problem. The issue was the grouping separator. It separated by leaving a space. So this is why I had inaccurate numbers. Now, since I needed all my numbers to stay in this format but change when I was doing calculations (Adding sums together - I wrote a class method that looks like this:

```
(NSString *)getDisplayAmountStringWithValue: (NSString *)value Currency: (NSString *)currency
{
    NSDecimalNumber *decimalValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""]];

    if ([decimalValue isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]]){
            decimalValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
    }

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

    if ([currency length] > 0){

            [formatter setPositivePrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currency]];
            [formatter setNegativePrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-", currency]];
    }else {
            [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];

    }

    NSString *newNumberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:decimalValue];

    return newNumberString;
}
```

Notice the `if` statement. I simply remove the space if I don't supply a currency (Which is not needed when adding sums together) - this along with my existing code, works perfectly.

Thanks for all the tips.